# What does syso-statements mean in Java?

Tags: java

What does `syso-statements` stand for in Java?

Comment: All that the answers here include, and... ... getting kicked real hard if used to do logging... Use a proper logging framework for that, and a proper debugger to debug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

short for `System.out.println();`

In eclipse you can type syso and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to fill out the expansion.

Answer (score 4):

Well, that's not a term that's commonly used, so you need to provide some context, but it most likely means system-out-statements.

That is, any statement that uses `System.out`

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is actually **Nothing**. And it doesn't even mean anything to the Eclipse IDE for Java. The real shortcut (actually template) is `sysout` and it stands for

```
System.out.println();
```

Java developers just stick to `syso` because it's shorter, Eclipse can match it to `sysout` and there is no other default template that matches `syso` so that Eclipse can just take the only match and replace it. You can add new and modify those templates in Eclipse preferences.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess here, System out statement.

e.g

```
System.out.println("Statement")
```