# java, why DataInputStream split String when whitespace

Tags: java, sockets, datainputstream

So I tried to learn `Socket` and `DataInputStream`.

While I try quite attempt, I realized that `DataInputStream` read string as divided, means like this:

**Client side:**

```
dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

String msg = "okay test some String"

dos.writeUTF(msg);
```

**ServerSide :**

```
dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

while(true){

    msg = dis.readUTF();

    Syso(msg);

}
```

**result:**

```
okay

test

some

String
```

I want to read `msg` fully in one line. What should I do?

Comment: I tested your program with a little bit of refactoring (it cannot compile like this) and it runs well. If you continue to get these errors,keep in mind that DataInputStream and DataOutputStream are using a custom UTF implementation and you can only use them for communication only between java apps. I would suggest you as also @Arun says to use Reader and writer interfaces, but `explicitly` specifying the Charset they use.

Comment: What does `Syso` do?

Comment: Neither `DataInputStream` nor `DataOutputStream` behaves as claimed here. Obviously `Syso` is to blame.

Comment: @Arun `writeUTF` includes a number of bytes for the rest of the string, and `readUTF` reads that number of bytes and the proceeds to read that number of bytes. It doesn't work like you think it does.

Comment: @Arun Worth a try why? and how is `readLine()` going to read data written by `writeUTF()`?

Comment: @EJP and Mark Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I deleted the suggestion. Will refer to the documentation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel looks like syso is shortcut for System.out.println in eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112965/what-does-syso-statements-mean-in-java

Comment: @Arun Not possible. That would not account for the extra lines in the least.

Comment: @Arun That is a rather big assumption, and would mean that the code shown isn't even the actual code, because `syso` in Eclipse is only a shorthand that needs to be expanded before it is usable.

Comment: Yes, better to wait for @ChangWonJeongJuicycool to explain Syso :)

Comment: sorry for delay, syso mean System.Out.println(); , und yes, i tryed to follow someone's advice who commented(but seems like erased now). i tryed BufferedReader and its works fine,  sorry for cannot upload complete codes, cause currently my code ist very nesty as hell.

Comment: Yes I deleted the comment. The suggestion was to change `dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())` to `dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputs()))` and `msg = dis.readUTF()` to `msg = dis.readLine()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `BufferedReader`

```
dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputs()))
while(true){
   msg = dis.readLine() 
   System.out.println(msg);
}
```

Or you can replace `System.out.println` with `System.out.print` which does not print a new line character at the end

```
dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
while(true){
   msg = dis.readUTF();
   System.out.print(msg+" ");
}
```